# Puppet-hiera-Function lookup() did not find a value-Windows

Tags: powershell, puppet, dsc, hiera

I installed dsc module and added AD user to Domain controller using puppet. Code below works fine when hard-coding password as plain text. Is it possible somehow to encrypt those passwords.

I read that  [hiera-eyaml](https://www.example42.com/2017/08/21/encrypt-your-secrets-with-hiera-eyaml/) is solution for this so i encrypted password

```
[root@PUPPET puppet]# /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml encrypt -p
Enter password: **********
string: ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAl/+uUACl6WpGAnA1sSqEuTp39SVYfHc7J0BMvC+a2C0YzQg1V]
```

Then stored that encrypted pass in /etc/common.eyaml file (specified in hiera config file)

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml edit /etc/common.eyaml
```

I can decrypt the file successfully:

```
 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml decrypt -f /etc/common.eyaml
```

Then i specified encrypted pass to manifest file

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:

```
 dsc_xADUser {'FirstUser':

            dsc_ensure => 'present',
            dsc_domainname => 'ad.contoso.com',
            dsc_username   => 'tfl',
            dsc_userprincipalname => 'tfl@ad.contoso.com',
            dsc_password   => {
            'user' => 'Administrator@ad.contoso.com',
            'password' => Sensitive('pass')
            },
            dsc_passwordneverexpires => true,
            dsc_domainadministratorcredential => {
            'user'  => 'Administrator@ad.contoso.com',
            'password' => Sensitive(lookup('password'))
            },



        }
```

On windows node i got error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'password' on node windows.example.com
```

Hiera config file:

```
cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
# Hiera 5 Global configuration file

---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Eyaml hierarchy"
    lookup_key: eyaml_lookup_key # eyaml backend
    paths:
       - "/etc/common.eyaml"
    options:
        pkcs7_private_key: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem"
        pkcs7_public_key: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem"

cat /etc/common.eyaml

 password: ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAl/+uUACl6WpGAnA1sSqEuTp39SVYfHc7J0BMvC+a2C0YzQg1V]
```

I'm new to Puppet and this hiera is confusing me

Comment: What are the contents of your `common.eyaml`?

Comment: just added at the end of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, there is a typo in your Hiera config file. The path to the data should be:

```
paths:
  - "/etc/common.eyaml"
```

After fixing that, you need to retrieve the value from Hiera. This is performed with the [puppet lookup function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/hiera_automatic.html#puppet-lookup). Since you have a single key value pair here in a single data file, this can be performed with a minimal number of arguments.

```
dsc_xADUser {'FirstUser':
  dsc_ensure            => 'present',
  dsc_domainname        => 'ad.contoso.com',
  dsc_username          => 'tfl',
  dsc_userprincipalname => 'tfl@ad.contoso.com',
  dsc_password   => {
    'user'     => 'Administrator@ad.contoso.com',
    'password' => Sensitive('pass')
  },
  dsc_passwordneverexpires => true,
  dsc_domainadministratorcredential => {
    'user'     => 'Administrator@ad.contoso.com',
    'password' => lookup('string'),
  },
}
```

However, you also really want to redact that password from your logs and reports. You would want to wrap that password String in a [Sensitive data type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_data_sensitive.html).

```
'password' => Sensitive(lookup('string')),
```

You seem to already be doing that for your other password that is being passed in as a String `pass`.

A side note to all of this is that Puppet has intrinsic support for lookup retrievals from Vault and Conjur in version 6, so that will become best practices instead of hiera-eyaml soon.

Comment: thanks @Matt, i'll try it tomorrow and report feedback, for a test i'm just tried to encrypt one entry in manifest file, if all goes fine, i'll apply it to rest of password. Just one note, `/etc/common.eyaml` contentt should be `password: ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAl/+uUACl6WpGAnA1sSqEuTp39SVYfHc7J0BMvC+a2C0YzQg1V]` ?

Comment: @xerks If you update the key in your data from `string` to `password`, then you will correspondingly need to update the key in your lookup like `lookup('password')`.

Comment: just tried `Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'password' on node windows.example.com   hiera --debug var environment=production
DEBUG: 2018-11-01 08:16:38 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2018-11-01 08:16:38 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml, skipping
nil
 `

Answer (score 1):

Ufff, after much struggling finally got it working:

```
 cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Eyaml hierarchy"
    lookup_key: eyaml_lookup_key # eyaml backend
    paths:
      - "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
      - "windowspass.eyaml"
    options:
        pkcs7_private_key: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem"
        pkcs7_public_key: "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem
```

Created password:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml encrypt -l 'password' -s 'Pass' --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem
```

Added it to /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/data/windowspass.eyaml file:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml edit windowspass.eyaml --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem



cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/data/windowspass.eyaml
---
password: ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAUopetXenh/+DN1+VesIZUI5y4k3kOTn2xa5uBrtGZP3GvGqoWfwAbYsfeNApjeMG+lg93/N/6mE9T59DPh]
```

Tested decryption:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml decrypt -f windowspass.eyaml --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem
```

As Matt suggested, mapped content of windowspass.eyaml to manifest file

```
'password' => Sensitive(lookup('password'))
```

Debugging command helped me a lot:

```
puppet master --debug --compile windows.example.com --environment=production
```

Thanks everyone, especially to Matt